# Energy Loss of protons travelling through gas

Tags: special-relativity, cosmic-rays

I wanted to calculated the energy loss of protons traveling through a gas medium such as helium and hydrogen.At energy range of about 10 Gev there should be two effects:1.Coulumb interaction,2.Creation of pions and other particles due to collision with the nucleus.Is it possible to precisely calculate the energy loss?

Comment: It is more complicated  . The energy loss of beams at CERN with the residual gas in the system for example is  estimated in a complicated way http://cds.cern.ch/record/328266/files/sl-97-037.pdf

Comment: A pion has a rest mass of ~140 MeV, so it doesn't seem like much energy would be lost from the 10 GeV (10,000 MeV) proton in the $pp\to pp\pi^0$ reaction. Almost certainly you'd end up with a distribution of energies, rather than a single energy. I wrote up (a decade ago!) [an answer on the $\pi^0$ energy spectrum](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/90035/25301) which has a bunch of reference that might be useful.